# font face not working for IE8 ?? getting @font-face encountered unknown error.?

Tags: html, css, fonts, internet-explorer-8, font-face

I am using font face to include a customised font named razing. The font is not working in IE8 but works well on IE9+ and other browsers. I checked the console in IE8 browser and i found " **@font-face encountered unknown error."** I tried using svg and fixes like **?#iefix** but it ain't working. Please can u provide a healthy solution to overcome this, Thanks !!

```
 <style>
  @font-face {
  font-family: Razing;
  src: url(Fonts/Razing/razing.eot);
  src: url(Fonts/Razing/razing.eot?#iefix) ,
 url(Fonts/Razing/razing.ttf),
 url(Fonts/Razing/razing.woff),
 url(Fonts/Razing/razing.svg) format('svg');

  }
.ABC{ font-family:Razing;font-size:20px;  }
</style>

 <p class="ABC"></p>
```

Comment: This is a copy-and-paste of a question asked thirteen minutes earlier by the same poster.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [font face not workibg for IE8 ?? getting @font-face encountered unknown error. ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23216163/font-face-not-workibg-for-ie8-getting-font-face-encountered-unknown-error)

Answer (score 0):

Try format('embedded-opentype') at the end of your #iefix line. e.g.

```
src: url(Fonts/Razing/razing.eot?#iefix) format('embedded-opentype'),
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit your font file, define identical names for Fontname, Family name and Name and export your TTF. You can use the [FontForge](http://fontface.codeandmore.com/blog/ie-7-8-error-with-eot-css3111/) application.

And then again convert it for web (EOT, WOFF).

[Read](http://fontface.codeandmore.com/blog/ie-7-8-error-with-eot-css3111/)

Make it work by downloading version of the TTF font and converted it for web.

CSS

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Razing';
    src: url('fonts/Razing.eot');
    src: url('fonts/Razing.eot?iefix') format('opentype'),
         url('fonts/Razing.woff') format('woff'),
         url('fonts/Razing.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```